# Reading a large structured binary file in Julia

Tags: julia, binaryfiles

I have a **large binary file containing identical records** with this memory layout:

```
# Julia code
struct Event
    ia::Int32
    ig::Int32
    Eg::Float64
    Tg::Float64
    xn::Float64
    yn::Float64
    zn::Float64

    # uninitialized constructor
    Event() = new()
end
```

How can I translate this C++ code in Julia?

```
// C++ code
struct Event
{
  int32_t ia;  
  int32_t ig;  
  double  Eg; 
  double  Tg;
  double  xn; 
  double  yn;
  double  zn;
};

// ... compute event_count

std::ifstream in(filename,std::ifstream::binary);
std::vector<Event> array(event_count);

in.read((char*)array.data(), event_count*sizeof(Event)); // <- Julia way: how to?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `read(filename, Event, n)`, where `n` is number of elements you want to read (size of target vector). Actually `n` can be e.g. a tuple giving dimensions of the output array.

You can check out help of `read` function for other options.

Comment: It is deprecated (0.7) and probably allocate n-size Vector every time. New way is something like `buffer = Array{Event}(uninitialized, n); read!(filename, buffer)` which is a little more similar to C++ in question. Problem is lack of [gcount](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/gcount/) in case of `n` is bigger than number of events that could be extracted from file.

Comment: @Liso thanks for this interesting additional information